# How to replace multiple substrings in a list of sentences using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I have a list of sentences as below :

```
sentences = ["I am learning to code", "coding seems to be intresting in python", "how to code in python", "practicing how to code is the key"]
```

Now I wish to replace few substrings in this list of sentences using dictionary of words and its replacements.

```
word_list = {'intresting': 'interesting', 'how to code': 'learning how to code', 'am learning':'love learning', 'in python': 'using python'}
```

I tried the following code:

```
replaced_sentences = [' '.join([word_list.get(w, w) for w in sentence.split()])
for sentence in sentences]
```

But only the one word string is getting replaced and not the keys with more than one word. It is because am using sentence.split() which tokenizes sentences word by word and misses out replacing substrings greater than one word.

How do I get to replace the substring with exact match using regex or any other suggestions?

expected output:

```
sentences = ["I love learning to code", "coding seems to be interesting using python", "learning how to code using python", "practicing learning how to code is the key"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to read if you break this into a function that replaces all the words for a single sentence. Then you can apply it to all the sentences in the list. Here we make a single regex by concaving all the keys of the dict with '|'. Then use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) grab the found value associated with the key, and return it as the replacement.

```
import re

def replace_words(s, word_lookup):
    rx = '|'.join(word_lookup.keys())
    return re.sub(rx, lambda match: word_lookup[match.group(0)], s)

[replace_words(s, word_list) for s in sentences]
```

This will result in:

```
['I love learning to code',
 'coding seems to be interesting using python',
 'learning how to code using python',
 'practicing learning how to code is the key']
```

You could optimize a bit by making the regex once instead of each time in the function. This would allow you to do something like:

```
import re

rx = re.compile('|'.join(word_list.keys()))
[rx.sub(lambda match: word_list[match.group(0)], s) for s in sentences]
```

Comment: Using dict with '|' is a great idea before using re.sub. Thank you!!